# Removing footer credit for this specific theme

Tags: licensing

I was wondering if after I purchased this theme I could remove the footer credit under a regular license for this theme?

https://themes.getbootstrap.com/product/boomerang-bootstrap-4-business-corporate-theme/

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

Source: https://themes.getbootstrap.com/licenses/

What you are describing is a "derivative work", or in the parlance of the above link, a "derivative theme". No license offered by the vendor allows for derivative themes.

Comment: There are a few licenses that allow removal of attribution, such as Creative Commons CC0, the WTFPL, and the Unlicense.  These are pretty much equivalent to putting the work in the public domain.

Comment: @DavidThornley: Fair enough. I haven't seen those in my searching (mostly I see Apache and MIT licenses). I've removed my personal anecdote, as it doesn't seem to be representative.